# Simple Blank Xamarin.Forms is failing with error. Deployment Failed-Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidSdkToolException:

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, deployment

Using latest VS2019, Windows10 Home. Just did nothing, but created a blank Xamarin.Forms app. Build successfully, fails deployment. Tried using different Android Emulators Oreo8.1 and Pie 9.0. Nothing worked. Getting same error Detailed output below:

```
Waiting for runtime checks to complete
 Detecting installed packages...
 Detecting installed packages...
 Creating C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Xamarin.Android\Cache\Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28.apk
 Creating C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Xamarin.Android\Cache\Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28.apk
 Copying platform assemblies...
 Copying platform assemblies...
 Copying file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
 Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v4.4\Mono.Android.Export.dll
Copying file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v4.4\OpenTK-1.0.dll
Copying file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v4.4\Mono.Android.Export.pdb
Copying file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v4.4\OpenTK-1.0.pdb
Copying file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\mono.android.dex
Copying file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\Mono.Android.dll
Copying file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\mono.android.jar
Copying file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\Mono.Android.pdb
Copying platform assemblies...
Creating: C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Temp\vt2chgrb.04s\AndroidManifest.xml
Creating: C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Temp\vt2chgrb.04s\unaligned.apk
Executing: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\aapt.exe package -f -0 .dll -0 .mdb -M "C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Temp\vt2chgrb.04s\AndroidManifest.xml" -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-29\android.jar" -F "C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Temp\vt2chgrb.04s\unaligned.apk" -k "C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Temp\vt2chgrb.04s\r"
Aapt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\aapt.exe exited with value: 0
Aapt
Creating: C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Temp\vt2chgrb.04s\unsigned.apk
Executing: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\zipalign.exe 4 "C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Temp\vt2chgrb.04s\unaligned.apk" "C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Temp\vt2chgrb.04s\unsigned.apk"
zipalign
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\zipalign.exe exited with value: 0
zipalign
Creating: C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Temp\vt2chgrb.04s\Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28.apk
Executing: C:\Program Files\Android\Jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\bin\java.EXE -jar "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\MSBuild\\Xamarin\\Android\\apksigner.jar" sign --ks "C:\\Users\\onlym\\AppData\\Local\\Xamarin\\Mono for Android\\debug.keystore" --ks-key-alias "androiddebugkey" --out "C:\\Users\\onlym\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\vt2chgrb.04s\\Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28.apk" --ks-pass "pass:android" --key-pass "pass:android" "C:\\Users\\onlym\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\vt2chgrb.04s\\unsigned.apk"
Removing temporary directory: C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Temp\vt2chgrb.04s
Creating C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Xamarin.Android\Cache\Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28.apk
1>Starting deployment to pixel_2_oreo_8_1_-_api_27 ...
1>Deploying to pixel_2_oreo_8_1_-_api_27 ...
Build started.
Project "AwApp.Android.csproj" (Install target(s)):
Found Java SDK version 1.8.0.
Found Java SDK version 1.8.0.
  PackageName: com.companyname.awapp
Dex Fast Deployment Enabled: False
MonoAndroid Tools: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\
Android Platform API level: 28
TargetFrameworkVersion: v9.0
Android NDK: 
Android SDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\
Android SDK Build Tools: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\
Java SDK: C:\Program Files\Android\Jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\
Application Java class: android.app.Application
Project "AwApp.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)):
Done building project "AwApp.csproj".
Project "AwApp.csproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):
Done building project "AwApp.csproj".
Project "AwApp.csproj" (GetNativeManifest target(s)):
Done building project "AwApp.csproj".
Skipping target "_VerifyXamarinAndroidSupportVersions" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_ResolveLibraryProjectImports" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_BuildLibraryImportsCache" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_GenerateAndroidResourceDir" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_GenerateLayoutBindings" because it has no outputs.
Skipping target "_ConvertResourcesCases" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CompileResources" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_PrepareUpdateAndroidResgen" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Checking Android SDK Build-tools version...
Selected Android SDK Build Tools Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\
Selected Android SDK Build Tools Version: 29.0.2
Android SDK Build Tools Version: 29.0.2 meets minimum requirements for Vector Drawables. OK.
Finished Checking Android SDK Build-tools version.
Skipping target "_UpdateAndroidResgen" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
  Adding assembly reference for AwApp.Android, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Net.Http, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Runtime.Serialization, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for System.ServiceModel.Internals, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for AwApp, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for netstandard, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Data, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Transactions, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Data.DataSetExtensions, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Drawing.Common, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.IO.Compression, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.IO.Compression.FileSystem, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.ComponentModel.Composition, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Web.Services, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for FormsViewGroup, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Java.Interop, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Mono.Android, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for mscorlib, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Core, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for Mono.Security, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Numerics, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Numerics.Vectors, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Runtime, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Xml, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Xml.Linq, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Runtime, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.ViewModel, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.AsyncLayoutInflater, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Collections, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.CoordinaterLayout, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.CursorAdapter, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomView, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Design, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.DocumentFile, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.DrawerLayout, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Interpolator, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Loader, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.LocalBroadcastManager, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Print, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.SlidingPaneLayout, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.SwipeRefreshLayout, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.VersionedParcelable, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.ViewPager, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Essentials, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Forms.Core, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Forms.Platform, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Forms.Xaml, recursively...
Skipping target "_CopyConfigFiles" because it has no inputs.
Skipping target "_ConvertPdbFiles" because it has no outputs.
Skipping target "_LinkAssembliesNoShrink" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CopyConfigFiles" because it has no inputs.
Skipping target "_ConvertPdbFiles" because it has no outputs.
Skipping target "_GenerateJavaStubs" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_ConvertCustomView" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_AddStaticResources" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_GeneratePackageManagerJava" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_GenerateAndroidAssetsDir" because it has no outputs.
Skipping target "_PrepareCreateBaseApk" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CreateBaseApk" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CompileJava" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CompileNativeAssemblySources" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CreateApplicationSharedLibraries" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CompileToDalvik" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Copying file from "C:\PersonalProjects\AwApp\AwApp.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\bin\com.companyname.awapp.apk" to "C:\PersonalProjects\AwApp\AwApp.Android\bin\Debug\com.companyname.awapp.apk".
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\zipalign.exe -p 4 "C:\PersonalProjects\AwApp\AwApp.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\bin\com.companyname.awapp.apk" "bin\Debug\\com.companyname.awapp-Signed.apk" 
C:\Program Files\Android\Jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\bin\java.exe -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\apksigner.jar" sign --ks "C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\xample2048DSA.keystore" --ks-pass pass:keypass --ks-key-alias publishingdoc --key-pass pass:keypass --min-sdk-version 26 --max-sdk-version 28  C:\PersonalProjects\AwApp\AwApp.Android\bin\Debug\com.companyname.awapp-Signed.apk 
Signed android package 'bin\Debug\com.companyname.awapp-Signed.apk'
Detecting installed packages...
Creating C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Xamarin.Android\Cache\Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28.apk
Copying platform assemblies...
Copying file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v4.4\Mono.Android.Export.dll
Copying file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v4.4\OpenTK-1.0.dll
Copying file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v4.4\Mono.Android.Export.pdb
Copying file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v4.4\OpenTK-1.0.pdb
Copying file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\mono.android.dex
Copying file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\Mono.Android.dll
Copying file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\mono.android.jar
Copying file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\Mono.Android.pdb
Creating: C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Temp\w2wxsblr.h5k\AndroidManifest.xml
Creating: C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Temp\w2wxsblr.h5k\unaligned.apk
Executing: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\aapt.exe package -f -0 .dll -0 .mdb -M "C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Temp\w2wxsblr.h5k\AndroidManifest.xml" -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-29\android.jar" -F "C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Temp\w2wxsblr.h5k\unaligned.apk" -k "C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Temp\w2wxsblr.h5k\r"
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\aapt.exe exited with value: 0
Creating: C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Temp\w2wxsblr.h5k\unsigned.apk
Executing: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\zipalign.exe 4 "C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Temp\w2wxsblr.h5k\unaligned.apk" "C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Temp\w2wxsblr.h5k\unsigned.apk"
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\zipalign.exe exited with value: 0
Creating: C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Temp\w2wxsblr.h5k\Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28.apk
Executing: C:\Program Files\Android\Jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\bin\java.EXE -jar "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\MSBuild\\Xamarin\\Android\\apksigner.jar" sign --ks "C:\\Users\\onlym\\AppData\\Local\\Xamarin\\Mono for Android\\debug.keystore" --ks-key-alias "androiddebugkey" --out "C:\\Users\\onlym\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\w2wxsblr.h5k\\Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28.apk" --ks-pass "pass:android" --key-pass "pass:android" "C:\\Users\\onlym\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\w2wxsblr.h5k\\unsigned.apk"
Removing temporary directory: C:\Users\onlym\AppData\Local\Temp\w2wxsblr.h5k
     
    ADB1000:  Deployment failed
    Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidSdkToolException: Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Failed to sign using signer "ANDROIDD"
        at com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner.signManifest(V1SchemeSigner.java:295)
        at com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner.sign(V1SchemeSigner.java:256)
        at com.android.apksig.DefaultApkSignerEngine.outputJarEntries(DefaultApkSignerEngine.java:657)
        at com.android.apksig.ApkSigner.sign(ApkSigner.java:442)
        at com.android.apksig.ApkSigner.sign(ApkSigner.java:193)
        at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.sign(ApkSignerTool.java:340)
        at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.main(ApkSignerTool.java:83)
    Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Failed to sign using SHA1withDSA
        at com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner.generateSignatureBlock(V1SchemeSigner.java:519)
        at com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner.signManifest(V1SchemeSigner.java:293)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: The security strength of SHA-1 digest algorithm is not sufficient for this key size
        at sun.security.provider.DSA.checkKey(DSA.java:111)
        at sun.security.provider.DSA.engineInitSign(DSA.java:143)
        at java.security.Signature$Delegate.init(Signature.java:1155)
        at java.security.Signature$Delegate.chooseProvider(Signature.java:1115)
        at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineInitSign(Signature.java:1179)
        at java.security.Signature.initSign(Signature.java:530)
        at com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner.generateSignatureBlock(V1SchemeSigner.java:515)
        ... 7 more
    
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Xamarin.AndroidTools.PlatformPackage.<GetPlatformPackagePathAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\77\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\PlatformPackage.cs:line 139
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<InstallSharedPlatformAsync>d__114.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\77\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Sessions\AndroidDeploySession.cs:line 349
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<EnsureCorrectSharedRuntimes>d__111.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\77\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Sessions\AndroidDeploySession.cs:line 270
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunAsync>d__110.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\77\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Sessions\AndroidDeploySession.cs:line 198
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>d__108.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\77\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Sessions\AndroidDeploySession.cs:line 123
    Done building project "AwApp.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.
    Build FAILED.
```

1>Deployment failed to pixel_2_oreo_8_1_-_api_27.
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Does this error cause by the code or not? You could create a new project to check. And if the code cause the error? Could you provide the code?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT not written a single line of code. Just default blank project as per tutorial

Comment: Have you try to repaire the VS? Does this work before?

Comment: It never worked. Tried many things. Updated VS2019. Tried to generate own signed .apk, but same error. Looks like jdk somehow not getting configured properly eveytime I reinstalled VS2019 with Mobile Developemt.

Comment: Does the reinstalled vs2019 work?